# Integration react-rails gem with npm components

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, npm

I have problem with installing this plugin https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube and use this in my js.cjsx react component. So I go step by step with this tutorial
http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/
But now how can I include and use react-youtube component in my js.cjsx file ?
I run `npm init` and `npm install react-youtube --save` before.
My application.js.coffee

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require turbolinks
#= require jquery
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
#= require alert
#= require react
#= require react_ujs
#= require components
#= require_tree .

React = require('react')
```

How Can I do this?